listings keywordstyle does not work inside NiceTabular

As you see above, I customized some keywords to show up in gray. This works for tabular but not NiceTabular environment
My MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{listings}

% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX-inline}{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    % style
    basicstyle=\linespread{1}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]
    {
        NiceTabular
    },
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{gray},
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|NiceTabular|

\lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|\vrule|

\smallskip

\begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=0.75ex]{@{}l}
    
    \lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|NiceTabular|
    \\
    
    \lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|\vrule|
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


Try morekeywords=[2]{NiceTabular} option without any line break!

@hair-splitter It does not work

It works, see my answer.

The following code works perfectly with TeX Live 2024.
Just remove the line break after the morekeywords=[2].
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX-inline}{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle=\linespread{1}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{NiceTabular}, % No line breaks before { sign
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{gray},
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|NiceTabular|

\lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|\vrule|

\smallskip 

\begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=0.75ex]{@{}l}
  \lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|NiceTabular|\\
  \lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|\vrule|\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



Adding keywords this way works only for a few keywords, it is better to simply add [2]% which works

This is technically the same thing I wrote!
